# twocolumn article cases alignment issues

Tags: amsmath, two-column, cases

I use the following option twocolumn

`\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}`

Images and almost everything works nice. 
However I face an issue with the mathmode `cases`
If my text is too long it doesn-t go automatically to the line and I don-t know how to set up manually the return line

For instance

```
\[
M_{ij}=\begin{cases}
1 & {\rm if\, employee\,}i\,{\rm has\, the\, required\, flight\, skills\, and\, language\, skills\, to\, be\, matched\, with\, employee\, j}\\
0 & {\rm otherwise}
\end{cases}
\]
```

Gives the following result after compilation

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `\rm` in LaTeX (it is not defined by default), and for text it is better to use text mode rather than math node and math spaces between words

so

```
0 & \text{otherwise}
```

or for your long example

```
1 & \parbox[t]{3cm}{if employee $i$ has ...matched with employee $j$}
```

where the length `3cm` can be adjusted to requirements.

Comment: Thx, hower if i put your code inside the \begin{cases{ \end{cases} is not working cuz I get a underfull \hbox badness mistake ?

Comment: L_{ij}=\begin{cases}
1 & \parbox[t]{3cm}{if employee $i$ has matched with employee $j$}
0 &  \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

Comment: @Swiss12000 (one reason why you should always provide full document not just fragments in your question) underfull hbox is not a error just a warning that it is hard to break lines to a narrow `3cm` measure, you could set it raggedright `\parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright if em....`  then TeX will not try to justify the narrow paragraph

Comment: Thanks it works. Yeah sorry I should put a MWE next time. Thanks ;)